# discord/google forms webhook only works when im the one posting, how can i fix this

Tags: google-apps-script

the webhook only runs when im the one posting to it, the permissions are set to anyone but that has not helped, it worked just fine not 2 months ago then google and discord changed some things and now its broken.

```
var POST_URL = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/sI9VjZ_v0TsMNA5yBWmkopvFX";

function onSubmit(e) {
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var allResponses = form.getResponses();
var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
var response = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
var items = [];

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = response[i].getResponse();
    try {
        var parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];
    } catch (e) {
        var parts = answer;
    }

    if (answer == "") {
        continue;
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            items.push({
                "name": question,
                "value": parts[j],
                "inline": false
            });
        } else {
            items.push({
                "name": question.concat(" (cont.)"),
                "value": parts[j],
                "inline": false
            });
        }
    }
}

var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
        "content": "‌", // This is not an empty string
        "embeds": [{
            "title": "Pirate Hunting",
            "fields": items,
            "footer": {
                "text": "Happy Hunting"
            }
        }]
    })
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
};
```

is there something wrong with the code or is this a permissions problem

Comment: It might be worth exploring the things that they changed.

Comment: It looks like you may have posted an api token in the url. You might want to be careful about secrets like these.

Comment: If that API key is real you need to revoke access to your application and geta new one ASAP. Never post tokens online.